# Binomial Probability Problem -HARD!

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

In the final match a boxer is facing another boxer and is expected to win 48% of the time. In reality they win 80% of the time.

What is the probability of that occurring in 10 matches?

2) In the very next match (in a different tournament), the boxer who won the previous match only wins 40% of the time.

- With the winning rate in the previous match, whats the probability of seeing that winning rate in 10 matches?

How would you go about this problem? I believe this a binomial problem but i do not know what the 48% and 80% are. Is one the varience and the other the expected mean? I dont know what equations i need in order to solve this problem. Also, how could I calculate this on excel. So if someone could guide me through this that would be great.

Comment: Letting $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, the binomial distribution says that $P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$. In your case the probabilities are $0.48$ and $0.8$

Comment: .So how would this be written for 100 matches?

Answer (score 4):

Both questions are VERY poorly written.

I'm pretty sure that the intention of the first question is for you to calculate the probability of winning exactly 8 matches if the probability of each win is 0.48

$$ P_8 = \binom{10}8 (0.48)^8 (0.52)^2  $$

I can't imagine what it is the second question wants.

Comment: I agree that they are poorly written that is why i am confused.So how would this be written for 100 matches?

Comment: for exactly 80 wins out of 100 ...
$$ P_{80} = \binom{100}{80} (0.48)^{80} (0.52)^{20}  $$

Comment: So if we were to put this in excel what would be placed in the variables BINOM.DIST (number_s,trials,probabilit_s,cumulative)?